# Referencing Django's versioned static resources

Tags: django

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, it makes a copy of each image, JavaScript, and CSS file with a hash in the filename:

```
Post-processed 'css/theme.css' as 'css/theme.afeb1fc222a9.css'
Post-processed 'css/custom.css' as 'css/custom.585e1b29ff9a.css'
...
```

I'm assuming this is just a way of making a versioned filename for better caching; the client or CDN can be told to cache this file indefinitely, because if I make a change, the hash will differ, and I'll just reference the new version by the new name.

However, I'm not clear on *how* I'm supposed to reference this URL. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) on serving static files just says,

> In your templates, either hardcode the url like `/static/my_app/example.jpg` or, preferably, use the `static` template tag to build the URL for the given relative path by using the configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE` storage (this makes it much easier when you want to switch to a content delivery network (CDN) for serving static files).

I went through my templates and dutifully switched every static resource (including the CSS files) from a hardcoded URL to a `{% static "..." %}` template tag, assuming it would map to the versioned filename where appropriate. But it doesn't.

I'm also using [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) for serving the resources, and I'm not entirely sure how it affects things, but it also says,

> Want forever-cacheable files and compression support? Just add this to your `settings.py`: `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

But I have that in my settings file and it also doesn't seem to do anything with these versioned filenames.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. Django by itself does not have this behaviour; Whitenoise is responsible for compressing these files and also for serving them. If something is not working, you should read the [Whitenoise documentation](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) on how to get it working with Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It seems that it's done by the [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) which is Django, not WhiteNoise. (WhiteNoise's storage backend inherits the behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DEBUG` is `True` then the static url will be `'css/theme.css'` instead of 
 `'css/theme.afeb1fc222a9.css'`

Comment: It seems that it's done by the [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) storage backend, which does specify that `DEBUG` has to be `False`. Thanks!